# Как присоединить таблицy dim_date для появления first_of_month_date в общей таблице

Tags: sql

У меня есть 2 таблицы,  для пустых строк нужно добавить верхнее значение. Проблема в том, что после объединения с таблицей dim_date даты пропущенных дат в общем запросе не отображаются. Например, именно для опреленного id я получила строки, но если без, я не могу.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863208/how-to-join-dim-date-table-for-appears-first-of-month-date

````
select first_day_of_month, last_value(c_loan_agreement_id) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY first_day_of_month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  c_loan_agreement_id from business_core.dim_date dd
left join business_core.fact_loan_agreement fla on date_trunc('month',fla.date_term_date)  = dd.first_day_of_month and dd.first_day_of_month <= '2023-12-01' and dd.first_day_of_month>= '2022-12-01' --and fla.c_loan_agreement_id= 'ALB000ab242-d005-4dc0-bf05-58dda00658a7'
where dd.first_day_of_month <= '2023-12-01' and dd.first_day_of_month>= '2022-12-01' 
group by  c_loan_agreement_id, first_day_of_month ```


etoo adoptivnoe query s uchetom commentarija

select first_day_of_month, date_trunc('month',nextdate::date) as nextdate ,  last_value(c_loan_agreement_id) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY first_day_of_month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  c_loan_agreement_id from business_core.dim_date dd
left join ( select c_loan_agreement_id, date_trunc('month', frr.repayment_date)::date as BOP, date_trunc('month',lead(frr.repayment_date,1)over(partition by c_loan_agreement_id order by frr.repayment_date)) as nextdate from  business_core.fact_receivable_repayment frr group by c_loan_agreement_id,bop,  repayment_date ) frr  on frr.bop <= dd.first_day_of_month and nextdate>dd.first_day_of_month 
where dd.first_day_of_month <= current_date and dd.first_day_of_month>= '2022-12-01' 
group by  c_loan_agreement_id, first_day_of_month, nextdate;  ```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRGje.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjnX5.png
````

Comment: Какая структура и содержание таблицы ``dim_date``?

Comment: @ValNik, eto kalendar. To est kajdui den unikaljnaja data, eto znachit chto first_day_of_month povtorjaetsja po chislu dnei v mecjace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите пример соединения таблицы с календарем. Календарь создан "на ходу", рекурсивным перебором дат от мин до макс даты.
Для соединения другой таблицы с календарем, в целевой таблице выбираем текущую и следующую дату `lead(EventDate,1,EventDate)over(partition by id order by EventDate) nextdate`.
Соединение с календарем должно быть от текущей даты до следующей. Т.е. соединяем текущую строку и календарь, поэтому значения текущей строки наследуются и в добавляемые (соединяемые) строки.

UPD. Добавлю тестовые данные, чтобы были разные Id. Запрос отработает правильно при разных Id, в том числе когда диапазоны пересекается.

```
WITH src AS (
SELECT  id,cast(EventDate as date) EventDate, value  
FROM(  VALUES   
       (4, '2022-12-30', 100.0)
      ,(4, '2023-01-04', 200.0)
      ,(4, '2023-01-07', 300)
      ,(5, '2023-01-04', 250)
      ,(5, '2023-01-07', 350)
   ) t (id,EventDate,Value)
)
,dim_date as (
  select 0 n,dateadd(d,0,(select min(EventDate) from src)) day_of_month
     , (select datediff(d,min(EventDate),max(EventDate)) from src) maxn
  union all
  select n+1,dateadd(d,1,day_of_month),maxn  from dim_date where n<maxn
)
,data as(
select id,EventDate,value
  ,lead(EventDate,1,EventDate)over(partition by id order by EventDate) nextdate
from src
)

SELECT t.id
  ,case when coalesce(n,0)=0  then EventDate
   else m.day_of_month
   end EventDate
  ,t.value
  ,m.n,nextdate,EventDate EventDate2 ,m.day_of_month cdate
FROM data t
left JOIN dim_date m on t.EventDate<=m.day_of_month and t.nextdate>m.day_of_month
order by id,EventDate
option (maxrecursion 500)
```

Пример результата запроса

| ID | EventDate | value | n | nextdate | EventDate2 | day_of_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-12-30 | 100.0 | 0 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-30 |
| 4 | 2022-12-31 | 100.0 | 1 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-31 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | 100.0 | 2 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-02 | 100.0 | 3 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2023-01-02 |
| 4 | 2023-01-03 | 100.0 | 4 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2023-01-03 |
| 4 | 2023-01-04 | 200.0 | 5 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 |
| 4 | 2023-01-05 | 200.0 | 6 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 |
| 4 | 2023-01-06 | 200.0 | 7 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-06 |
| 4 | 2023-01-07 | 300.0 | null | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-07 | null |
| 5 | 2023-01-04 | 250.0 | 5 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 |
| 5 | 2023-01-05 | 250.0 | 6 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 |
| 5 | 2023-01-06 | 250.0 | 7 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-06 |
| 5 | 2023-01-07 | 350.0 | null | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-07 | null |

Возможно, Вам больше подойдет такой вариант, когда нужны остатки не по дням, а начало месяца:

```
WITH src AS (
SELECT  id,cast(EventDate as date) EventDate, value  
FROM(  VALUES   
       (4, '2022-12-30', 100.0)
      ,(4, '2023-01-04', 200.0)
      ,(4, '2023-01-07', 300)
      ,(4, '2023-02-08', 201)
  
      ,(5, '2023-01-04', 250)
      ,(5, '2023-03-07', 350)
      ,(5, '2023-04-05', 350)
   ) t (id,EventDate,Value)
)
,dim_date as (
  select 0 n,datefromparts((select year(min(EventDate)) from src)
                ,(select month(min(EventDate)) from src)
              ,1) first_day_of_month
     , (select eomonth(max(EventDate)) from src) maxDate
  union all
  select n+1,dateadd(mm,1,first_day_of_month),maxDate  from dim_date 
  where dateadd(m,1,first_day_of_month)<=maxDate
)
,data as(
select id,EventDate,value
  ,lead(EventDate,1,EventDate)over(partition by id order by EventDate) nextdate
from src
)
--select * from dim_date
  
SELECT t.id
  ,case when EventDate>first_day_of_month  then EventDate
   else m.first_day_of_month
   end EventDate
  ,t.value
  ,m.n,nextdate,EventDate EventDate0 ,m.first_day_of_month first_day 
FROM data t
left JOIN dim_date m 
  on 
   ( first_day_of_month between eventdate and nextdate )
  or
   ( month(t.EventDate)=month(first_day_of_month)   )
order by id,EventDate
option (maxrecursion 500)
```

Результат запроса на этих тестовых данных

| id | EventDate | value | n | nextdate | EventDate0 | first_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-12-30 | 100.0 | 0 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | 100.0 | 1 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-04 | 200.0 | 1 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-07 | 300.0 | 1 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-02-01 | 300.0 | 2 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-02-01 |
| 4 | 2023-02-08 | 201.0 | 2 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-02-01 |
| 5 | 2023-01-04 | 250.0 | 1 | 2023-03-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | 2023-02-01 | 250.0 | 2 | 2023-03-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-02-01 |
| 5 | 2023-03-01 | 250.0 | 3 | 2023-03-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-03-01 |
| 5 | 2023-03-07 | 350.0 | 3 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-03-07 | 2023-03-01 |
| 5 | 2023-04-01 | 350.0 | 4 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-03-07 | 2023-04-01 |
| 5 | 2023-04-05 | 350.0 | 4 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-04-01 |

[Пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/l36yEPFj)

Другой пример, для случая, когда последняя добавленная запись должна быть началом следующего месяца от последней записи в таблице.

```
WITH src AS (
SELECT  id,cast(EventDate as date) EventDate, value  
FROM(  VALUES   
       (4, '2022-12-30', 100.0)
      ,(4, '2023-01-04', 200.0)
      ,(4, '2023-01-07', 300)
      ,(4, '2023-02-08', 201)
  
      ,(5, '2023-01-04', 250)
      ,(5, '2023-03-31', 350)
      ,(5, '2023-04-01', 360)
   ) t (id,EventDate,Value)
)
,dim_date as (
  select 0 n,datefromparts((select year(min(EventDate)) from src)
                ,(select month(min(EventDate)) from src)
              ,1) first_day_of_month
     , dateadd(d,1,(select eomonth(max(EventDate)) from src)) maxDate
  union all
  select n+1,dateadd(mm,1,first_day_of_month),maxDate  from dim_date 
  where dateadd(m,1,first_day_of_month)<=maxDate
)
,data as(
select id,EventDate,value
  ,lead(EventDate)over(partition by id order by EventDate) nextdate
from src
)
  
SELECT t.id
  ,case when EventDate>first_day_of_month  then EventDate
   else m.first_day_of_month
   end EventDate
  ,t.value
  ,m.n,nextdate,EventDate EventDate0 ,m.first_day_of_month first_day 
FROM data t
left JOIN dim_date m 
  on 
   ( first_day_of_month between eventdate and nextdate )
  or
   ( month(t.EventDate)=month(first_day_of_month)   )
  or 
   ( first_day_of_month=dateadd(d,1,eomonth(eventdate)) and nextdate is null)
order by id,EventDate
option (maxrecursion 500)
```

Результат запроса на этих тестовых данных

| d | EventDate | value | n | nextdate | EventDate0 | first_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-12-30 | 100.0 | 0 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | 100.0 | 1 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-30 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-04 | 200.0 | 1 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-01-07 | 300.0 | 1 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 2023-02-01 | 300.0 | 2 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-01-07 | 2023-02-01 |
| 4 | 2023-02-08 | 201.0 | 2 | null | 2023-02-08 | 2023-02-01 |
| 4 | 2023-03-01 | 201.0 | 3 | null | 2023-02-08 | 2023-03-01 |
| 5 | 2023-01-04 | 250.0 | 1 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | 2023-02-01 | 250.0 | 2 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-02-01 |
| 5 | 2023-03-01 | 250.0 | 3 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-03-01 |
| 5 | 2023-03-31 | 350.0 | 3 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-03-01 |
| 5 | 2023-04-01 | 350.0 | 4 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-04-01 |
| 5 | 2023-04-01 | 360.0 | 4 | null | 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-01 |
| 5 | 2023-05-01 | 360.0 | 5 | null | 2023-04-01 | 2023-05-01 |

При выборке следующей даты, используем признак отстутвия следующей записи по данному Id - null в поле nextdate.
Также имеется 2 записи в результате с датой 2023-04-01 а)на начало месяца б)за этот день.

Структрура и назначение Вашей талблицы dim_date так и осталась неизвестной;)

Comment: Spasibo! Seichas poprobuju, dumaju v soedenenii bula problema

Comment: napisala query s uchetom vashego commentarija( dobavleno v opisanije, vse ravno ne rabotaet kak nado. Potomu chto vashe query v ramkax odnogo id, moje toje v raamkax odnogo idi rabotaet, a vot kogda ih bolshe ne schitaet kak nado

Comment: Добавил тестовые данные, чтобы посмотреть как работает при разных Id. Работает. Покажите в общем виде, как Вы соединяете таблицы. Возможно, мы по разному понимаем Вашу таблицу Календарь. В одном месте упоминается first_day_of_month, т.е. 1 запись на месяц, в другом "по числу дней в месяце", т.е. каждый день. Уточните, пожалуйста структуру календаря.

Comment: @VakNik struktura kak vu i ponjali, kajdui den imeetsja, a first?day?of?month povtorjaetsja po kolichestvu dnei. To est 1-1-2023 budet povtorjatsja 31 raz.

Comment: vtoroi variant poshti podhodi, est odin njuans....nujno ostanovitsja schitat vakue ne na poslednei date netdate, a na 1 chisle tekujshego mecjaca, to est dlja vashego id  = 4 nujno bulo ostanovitsja na 1-03-2023, nesmotrja na to chto oplata bula v fevrale.

Comment: U vas ochen horoshaja rabota, skajite kak nauchilis tak effectivno razbiratsja  v SQL, mojet kursu mojete possovetovat?

Comment: @VakNik i eshe u menja est 2 stolbca. odin nujno v odnom nujno protjagivat value(ostatok), v drugom net(oplata), kak but v etm sluchae.

Comment: Другие столбцы также как и value, если их способ вычисления такой же. В общем виде - сперва вычисляете значения, потом их протягиваете по отчетным датам, т.к. они не отличаются от значения на дату последней операции в месяце.  По поводу курсов - очень полезный и интересный ресурс sql-ex.ru

Comment: v tom r to i delo chto otlichajutsja, vtoroi stolbec doljen 0 pokazuvat - eto oplata, kotoroi po faktu ne bulo v posledujushih mecjacah,.

Comment: kajetsja ponjala, porobuju union ispolzovat dlja soedinenija tablic s raznumi uslovijami - doljno srabotat